# creating unique yet ordered ,order number for a customer's order

Tags: java, unique

In my `java` app I need to generate a `unique order number` for a `customer's order`.I thought the `time of creation of order` is a good enough unique value.`Two orders cannot be created at the same second`.
To prevent  others from using the ordernumber, by guessing some creationtime value,I appended a part of `hash` of the creationtime string to it and made it the final order number string.

Is there any unseen pitfall in this approach?Creating the order number based on time of creation was intended to give some sort order for the created orders in the system..
The code is given here

```
public static String createOrderNumber(Date orderDate) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        String datestring = df.format(orderDate).toString();
        System.out.println("datestring="+datestring);
        System.out.println("datestring size="+datestring.length());
        String hash = makeHashString(datestring);//creates SHA1 hash of 16 digits
        System.out.println("hash="+hash);
        System.out.println("hash size="+hash.length());
        int datestringlen = datestring.length();
        String ordernum = datestring+hash.substring(datestringlen,datestringlen+5);
        System.out.println("ordernum size="+ordernum.length());
        return ordernum;
    }

    private static String makeHashString(String plain) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        final int MD_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 16;
        final String HASH_ALGORITHM = "SHA1";
        String hash = null;
         try {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_ALGORITHM);
                md.update(plain.getBytes());
                BigInteger hashint = new BigInteger(1, md.digest());
                hash = hashint.toString(MD_PASSWORD_LENGTH);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
                throw(nsae);
            }
        return hash;
    }
```

A sample output is

```
datestring=20110924103251
datestring size=14
hash=a9bcd51fc69d9225c5d96061d9c8628137df14e0
hash size=40
ordernum size=19
ordernum=2011092410325125c5d
```

Comment: *"Two orders cannot be created at the same second"* They can if the server is processing 20 orders per second.

Comment: thats a lot of code and conversions when you can just use an integer and increment it.... whats wrong with orderNo++? lol

Answer (score 1):

One potential issue cn arise if your application runs on cluster of servers.
In this case if it happens that this code is executed simultanesously in two JVMs tha same orders will be generated.

If this is not the case, the unique order number generation based on the dates sounds ok to me.
I didn't really understood the meaning of hash here.
I mean from the cryptography point of view it doesn't really add a security to your code. If a "malicious" client guesses the order number, its enough to know that the SHA1 hash is applied, the algorithm itself is known, and may be applied to determine the order number.

Hope this helps

Comment: Appending a modified form of the user emailaddress(like user1-gmail-com) to the creationtime string  may create a unique order number ,if the app runs in clusters

Comment: @jimgardener, This makes it less likely, but not impossible.  You could add the milli-seconds to creation time. However there should be a central store (e.g. a database) which you can check if the id is unique. i.e. what are you going to do with the id anyway? Why does it need to be unique?

Comment: well I thought ,a unique ordernumber would be required for communication btw shopadmin and the customer

Answer (score 0):

If needed an unique it should always be from a 3rd party system which is common and the receiving/calculating method should be through a synchronized method where this will happens sequential or can be generated through database system which will be almost always unique.